# Saving the audio file when using Android's speech recognition

Tags: android, voice

Is there a way to save the file that is recorded when using Android's voice/speech recognition software? I tried the alternative of both recording and using the speech recognition at the same time, but this doesn't seem to work; probably because Android itself won't let two activities use the microphone at the same time. Of course, finding where (and if) the file is saved would be much better.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463875/how-does-google-keep-do-speech-recognition-while-saving-the-audio-recording-at-t?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

When using RecognitionListener, the function onBufferReceived reads the speech into a buffer, which you can collect.

Comment: Check documentation: 

public abstract void onBufferReceived (byte[] buffer)
More sound has been received. The purpose of this function is to allow giving feedback to the user regarding the captured audio. **There is no guarantee that this method will be called**.